# Determine which function is above the other.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the area between 2 functions. I have no calculator but have equations. I want to determine which function is above the other so I subtract integral in correct order. Is there a way to do that other than finding points?

These are the 2 functions, 
$y=-x^2$ and $y=-x^3+6x$

Integrate from -2 to 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com) to plot the functions:

[image: page 1]

As you can see in one part one figure is above and in other part another.

Hope you can solve it further.

Answer (score 0):

To find the limits of integration, I suppose you looked for the points of intersection. Note that they intersect not only in $x=-2$ and $x=3$, but also in $x=0$.

It is thus possible that the 'upper' function is not the same in the intervals $[-2,0]$ and $[0,3]$; in fact: it will change in $x=0$ in your case.

Now in each of those intervals, you can easily plug in a value for $x$ to check which function is the larger one. Is there a reason why you want to avoid this, or what do you mean by *other than finding points*? Take easy values, e.g. $x=-1$ and $x=1$.

Alternatively: you can calculate the integrals on the two intervals (separately!) by subtracting one from the other *at random*. Then simply  take the absolute value: if you accidentally subtracted the larger from the smaller (you'll get the opposite value), the absolute value covers for this.

---

Applying this to $\color{red}{f(x)=-x^2}$ and $\color{blue}{g(x)=-x^3+6x}$; the area enclosed by the graphs is given by:
$$\int_{-2}^3 \left| \color{red}{f(x)}-\color{blue}{g(x)} \right| \,\mbox{d}x = \int_{-2}^0  \color{red}{f(x)}-\color{blue}{g(x)} \,\mbox{d}x +\int_{0}^3  \color{blue}{g(x)}-\color{red}{f(x)} \,\mbox{d}x $$
because $\color{red}{f(x)} \ge \color{blue}{g(x)}$ on $[-2,0]$ and $\color{red}{f(x)} \le \color{blue}{g(x)}$ on $[0,3]$.

If you don't want to check this, you can simply do:
$$\int_{-2}^3 \left| \color{red}{f(x)}-\color{blue}{g(x)} \right| \,\mbox{d}x = \left|\int_{-2}^0  \color{red}{f(x)}-\color{blue}{g(x)} \,\mbox{d}x\right|  +\left|\int_{0}^3 \color{red}{f(x)}-\color{blue}{g(x)} \,\mbox{d}x\right|  $$

Comment: I did that but it takes way too long.

Comment: Plugging in $x=\pm 1$ takes _too long_...?! By the way: I added a paragraph.

Comment: So if I use absolute value the order doesn't matter? That seems better idea.

Comment: Correct: but then you still have to split into two integrals and take the absolute value of both integrals. If you take the absolute value not _of the integral_, but _of the difference of the functions_, then you'll have _written_ it with a single integral but you'll still need to split it into two to calculate it.